# Covariance and Correlation with User Defined Function

Tags: python, numpy, user-defined-functions

My Task is to write two user-defined functions to calculate Covariance and correlation,
**using only numpy.sum, numpy.mean and numpy.std.**

So far I have written these user defined functions :

```
# x and y are two data (series) as input parameters 
#the 'mag and 'depth' are from my Data 

def cov(x, y): 
    mean_x,mean_y = np.mean(x), np.mean(y) 
    n = len(x) 
    return sum((x - mean_x) * (y - mean_y)) / n 


def corr(x,y):
    x_std= np.std (x)
    y_std= np.std (y)
    return cov(x,y) / (np.std(x)*np.std(y))
```

When I compare my data with numpy.corrcoef() something else comes out.

```
cov(df['mag'],df['depth']) 
corr(df['mag'],df['depth']) 
np.corrcoef(df['mag'],df['depth'])
```

My Results are:

```
2.144665744323871

0.32569403447524437

array([[1.        , 0.32569403],
       [0.32569403, 1.        ]])
```

My Data is:
#I use the 'mag' and 'depth' from here

```
data_url ='https://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/all_month.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(data_url)
df.dropna(inplace=True)
df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace =True)
df
```

I can't find the error, does anyone have any tips?Thanks!

Comment: your correlation is correct.. what is the question here? `np.corrcoef` always return a pairwise correlation matrix. You can see that the diagonal values are identical

Comment: yes, now I noticed it

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you are right. It appears that the `np.corrcoef()` function returns the **correlation coefficient matrix**. As you can see the diagonal is made of 1's cause the correlation of one variable with herself is 1. As for the other values, they are a correlation of the variables x,y which is the same for the correlation of y,x.